# Keras and pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I want to build up this basic Keras model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=9, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
    data_train, label_train,
    validation_split=0.2,
    batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epoch, verbose=verbose)
```

There for data_train I wanted to use a Series which I took out of a DataFrame:

```
import os
path = "Dataset/pic_train"   
cnt = 0 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["FileName", "PicData"])
dataArray = []

for file in os.listdir(path):

    fullFileStr= "{}/{}".format(path,file)

    data = readPic(fullFileStr).reshape(1,-1)[0] 
    """
        "readPic" reads a jpg file with PIL.Image and returns it as a nxm pixel numpy.ndarray.
        reshape(1,-1)[0] shall convert it into a 1 dimensional vector array.
        This shall be the input vector for the nn later.
    """

    dataArray.append(data)

    df.loc[cnt] = {"FileName" : file, "PicData" : data}
    cnt = cnt + 1


dataArray = np.array(dataArray)
```

The created DataFrame looks like this (simplified with 2 pictures):

> | FileName  || PicData |
>
> | file1.jpg || [70, 199, 61, 191, 214, 223, 255, 255, 255] |
>
> | file2.jpg || [188, 192, 188, 187, 73, 192, 183, 172, 189] |

(The content of PicData here is just 9 pixels for testing. Usually I have around 256 pixels(so 64x64 pictures) here. Now I wanted to feed this PicData into the model.

Therefore to pass this into my Keras model I need to use the numpy vector again using:

```
df.loc[:,"PicData"].values
```

What I expect now that the model receives a matrix of (2,9) elements. So 2 pictures with 9 pixels (to match the example from above). Where each pixel is a feature...

However the shape of this ndarray is an array with the shape (2,) and not (2, 9) like the the shape of "dataArray".

I have the feeling that this information is needed because if I pass "df.loc[:,"PicData"].values" to my model I get the error message:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_3_input to have
>   shape (9,) but got array with shape (1,)

And when I pass the dataArray to the model it works (my pictures are currently only 9 Pixels for testing).

So here I am not sure what the best way is in order to solve this.
Can someone give me a feedback here?
Bascially what the DataFrame returns is not wrong so I have a feeling that my input vectors of my nn are maybe wrongly defined for this type of vector....?

Comment: @Troy-d hm... ok my question is a bit confusing. In general your first assumption was correct and I want to train my model on giving 9 rows with 1 column. In this column I have an array of pixels in. I updated my question to make it more clearer.

Comment: Updated the answer, maybe that's getting closer to the issue.

Comment: What is df.shape?

Comment: Hi @TroyD, you are right: I am using a column that contains a list instead of 9 separate columns. Is this the wrong approach for a problem like that? In general: When I store the data of a picture in a DataFrame would it be more common to have one column (= one Feature) per pixel? So in a 256x256 pixel picture this would be 65535 columns.... My idea was that I hold the list as a single feature (PicData) and provide this to the model for training. To your question: df.shape at the end of the "for loop" is (2,2): 2 lines for 2 pictures and 2 columns ("FileName" To and "PicData")

Comment: Also a question to your latest answer: How can I create a DataFrame like this: "| file1.jpg || 70, 199, 61, 191, 214, 223, 255, 255, 255 |" instead of "| file2.jpg || [188, 192, 188, 187, 73, 192, 183, 172, 189] |".

Comment: Ok, think I got it now. Updated the answer

Comment: Hi @TroyD, ok this is good to know. then my approach was wrong. Then  I checked the link and after a first look it seems that they completely avoid pandas here... So I will align my code to that. However just for interest. If I would want a DataFrame instance, would this be the correct way to create the DataFrame with 10 columns (FileName + 9 pixels) and add the data to it: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(9 + 1))
df = df.rename(columns={0:"FileName"})
df.loc[0] = "file1.jpg"
df.iloc[0,1:] = data
data2 = data * 2 # (Some testdata)
df.loc[1] = "file2.jpg"
df.iloc[1,1:] = data2

Comment: That's just one example, you can find a lot of others that use Pandas, so don't be afraid to do that either.  For creating the dataframe, you'll want to crate the index first otherwise df.loc[] won't work.  df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(n), columns=range(9 + 1))  I don't think df.loc[0] = "file1.jpg" will work.  You'd want df.iloc[0, 0] = "file1.jpg", then df.iloc[0, 1:] = data.  You might just want to make the file names the index, then you could have df.loc["file1.jpg"] = data.

Comment: Ok I got this. Thank you @TroyD for your effort. This was a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your dataframe:

```
| FileName || PicData |
| file1.jpg || [70, 199, 61, 191, 214, 223, 255, 255, 255] |
| file2.jpg || [188, 192, 188, 187, 73, 192, 183, 172, 189] |
```

You have n samples, and one column.  The column contains lists that contain all the pixel data from your pictures.  So when you're referencing df.loc[:,"PicData"].values, that's only one column, so your output will be n by 1 and a list, instead of n by 9 numpy array as the model requires.  You could work around this by referencing the list and then extracting the values, but you won't want to do that, as I'll explain below.  The way you should approach this problem is to put all of your data into a pandas dataframe or numpy array with each row being a sample and a separate column for all the pixel data.

```
| FileName || pixel1, pixel2, pixel3, ..., pixel9 |
| file1.jpg || 70, 199, 61, 191, 214, 223, 255, 255, 255 |
| file2.jpg || 188, 192, 188, 187, 73, 192, 183, 172, 189 |
```

There are a few reasons why you wouldn't want to use the list approach.  First, Keras requires a numpy array as input.  So if your data is in a list form, you'll have to convert it to numpy array anyway before you can load it in the model, which will be very slow as you'll have to do this list by list, row by row.  Here's the source code from Keras for fitting a model:

```
def fit(self, x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1, callbacks=None,
        validation_split=0., validation_data=None, shuffle=True,
        class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, **kwargs):
    """Trains the model for a fixed number of epochs.

    # Arguments
        x: input data, as a Numpy array or list of Numpy arrays
            (if the model has multiple inputs).
        y: labels, as a Numpy array.
```

Second, the advantage of using numpy in machine learning is that numpy stores data efficiently for use in matrix algebra operations.  Lists are not optimized for this purpose, so you'll get much worse performance if you tried to do operations in this manner.

It's fine to flatten your 256x256 image and have one column for each pixel.  That's pretty standard, and you'll find a lot of examples to walk you through it.

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html